# First Order Logic Sentences Using Arithmetic Language

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Considering the following:

Constants: $0, 1$

Functional Symbols: $+, .$

Relational Symbols: $<, |$ (| denotes divisibility)

Is it possible to write the following sequences using First Order Logic?

1. There are infinite prime numbers (how to represent infinite?)
2. Every subset of Natural Numbers has a minimum element (how to represent the subset?)

If it is not possible, what is missing? Could we extend the language in order to represent that?

Comment: Divisibility is redundant when interpreted in natural numbers: $(x \mid y) \equiv (\exists z: y=zx)$.

Comment: See this is a weird question.  The answer is either "no", because we don't have a symbol for prime, or "yes" because we can just trivially write an equivalent statement that is either true or false.  There is really no reason to pretend that one equivalent statement is better than another equivalent statement.  For example, (1) could be written $\forall x ~x = x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, it is. 
   $$
   \forall x \exists p \forall d \colon x < p \wedge 1 < p \wedge (1 < d \wedge d < p \rightarrow \neg d | p).
   $$
   This sentence states that for all $x$ there is some $p$ that is not divisible by any $d$ such that $1 < d < p$ or even simpler: There are unboundedly (and hence infinitely) many primes.
2. We can't can't quantify over subsets in first order logic. However, we can do so in second order logic. In the following I reserve capital letters for subsets of our model, while lowercase letters denote elements thereof. Now consider the following sentence in second order logic over the language $\{0,1,+,\cdot, | \}$:
   $$
   \forall X \exists m \forall n \colon \neg X(n) \vee [X(m) \wedge (n < m \rightarrow \neg X(n))].
   $$
   It states that for every subset $X$, $X$ is empty or there is some $m \in X$ such that there is no $n < m$ that is an element of $X$, i.e. $X$ is empty or there is some minimal $m \in X$.

Comment: Thanks! But why can't we talk about subsets in first order logic?

Comment: @LuizS. Well, that's not true. What I wanted to say is that we can't quantify over subsets of a given model in first order logic - by definition of first order logic. We can however talk about subsets by introducing new predicate symbols to our language.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks. So, I could introduce the symbol $\subset$, but I can't pick a subset X of the domain then say something like $\forall X, \exists m: X(m)$ in first order logic?

Comment: No, what you can do is to introduce new predicate symbols $(R_{i} \mid i \in I)$ to your language and interpret each $R_{i}$ as a specific subset of your model. You can even do this for every subset of your model. However, you cannot quantify over these predicates, so there is no first order sentence that takes all these subsets (more precisely, their predicate symbols) into account. At this point you can either formulate a meta-sentence that says 'for each predicate symbol $R_{i}$ a first order sentence $\phi_{R_{i}}$ holds'. Or you can use second order logic instead.

Comment: The latter allows you to write down a single sentence that talks about all subsets of your model - as you can see in my answer.

Comment: I see now, thank you again for the explanation!

Comment: @LuizS. You're very welcome.